# Only able to ping cabled machines but not wireless ones

Tags: wireless-networking

In my company's local network, everyone can only ping cabled machines but not any wireless ones. We used some "invisible" router arrangement so that we would only see one SSID even though the connection is provided by multiple ones (to internet through a single host, though).

Any ideas on why this happen and how should I fix this?

Comment: Because the WiFI access points aren't access points but routers maybe? But really, you should supply much more information if you want a godd answer.

Comment: Sorry for the pain, man, I wish I know what I shall provide. Any particular points I can start from?

Comment: Issues specific to corporate IT support and networks are off topic, see [On-Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Please talk to your IT department.

Comment: @JasonM To clarify: That's _your_ pain. Not mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure all the APs are just bridging (not doing NAT or IP routing) between the WLAN and the LAN. You want your whole Ethernet LAN and Wireless LAN together to be like one big bridged/switched LAN, with a single NAT gateway (if any) and a single DHCP server. Running NAT (or IP routing) in your Wi-Fi APs would cause wired LAN machines to be unable to ping wireless clients.
2. Make sure any "client isolation" or "port isolation" features of your APs  are disabled. Some APs have this kind of feature to intentionally keep local devices from being able to reach each other directly.

Comment: Thanks. After bugging the forks who set up the network (who are not IT pros), they said that we are using different channels on different routers to  make them acting like one. I guess that brings problems and would require physically connecting to the routers to check out. That does not seem easy, so I will just cable the machines together instead.